# Why initializing a value by itself is not throwing any error in C?

Tags: c, initialization, assignment-operator

I came up with this issue whilst practicing assignment in **C**. When I try to initialize any variable with it's name(identifier), which doesn't even exist, is not throwing any kind of error.

```
int x = x;
```

As far as I know associativity of assignment operator is right to left. So the following code should throw an error whilst i'm initializing a variable with an rvalue which doesn't even exist. Rather, it's assigning some kind of garbage value to it. Why is this happening?

Comment: `int x /* x exists now though it hasn't been assigned a value yet */ = x /* UB: using garbage value (should work "sanely" on any current computer) for initialization */;`

Comment: The compiler only checks syntax. It is a valid statement. It is up to the programmer to be correct.

Comment: @stark: Compilers do not only check syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Setting value to be itself is undefined behavior in c standard. After appending compiler option `-Winit-self` and warning occurs.

Comment: If it's invalid, than why it's not generating any kind of error?

Comment: Even worse: Why isn't it not even giving a warning? (gcc -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic)

Comment: Setting a value to itself is perfectly fine and for some types even meaningfull. For example outputing a character read from a UART in embedded systems would be: `*UART_DR = *UART_DR;`. The problem here is that `x` on the right is uninitialized.

Comment: It is not an “invalid operation for compiler”. The C standard does not define the behavior of using an uninitialized automatic object whose address is not taken, but neither does it impose a constraint requiring a compiler to diagnose it.

Comment: After adding this compiler option `-Winit-self`, warning occurs.

Answer (score 0):

[GCC 11.2 does diagnose this if you use `-Wuninitialized -Winit-self`.](https://godbolt.org/z/rWxT5G14a)

I suspect `int x = x;` may have been used as an idiom<sup>1</sup> for “I know what I am doing; do not warn me about `x` being uninitialized,” and so it was excluded from `-Wuninitialized`, but a separate warning was provided with `-Winit-self`.

Note that while the behavior of `int x = x;` is not defined by the C standard (if it is inside a function and the address of `x` is not taken), neither does it violate any constraints of the C standard. This means a compiler is not required to diagnose the problem. Choosing to issue a warning message is a matter of choices and quality of the C implementation rather than rules of the C standard.

Apple Clang 11.0 does not warn for `int x = x;` even with `-Wuninitialized -Winit-self`. I suspect this is a bug (a deviation from what the authors would have wanted, if not from the rules of the C standard), but perhaps there was some reason for it.

Consider code such as:

```
int FirstIteration = 1;
int x;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (FirstIteration)
        x = 4;
    x = foo(x);
    FirstIteration = 0;
}
```

A compiler might observe that `x = 4;` is inside an `if`, and therefore reason that `x` might not be initialized in `foo(x)`. The compiler might be designed to issue a warning message in such cases and be unable to reason that the use of `FirstIteration` guarantees that `x` is always initialized before being used in `foo(x)`. Taking `int x = x;` as an assertion from the author that they have deliberately designed the code this way gives them a way to suppress the spurious warning.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> There are several idioms which are used to tell a compiler the author is deliberately using some construction which is often an error. For example, `if (x = 3) …` is completely defined C code that sets `x` to 3 and always evaluates as true for the `if`, but it is usually a mistake as `x == 3` was intended. The code `if ((x = 3)) …` is identical in C semantics, but the presence of the extra parentheses is an idiom used to say “I used assignment deliberately,” and so a compiler may warn for `if (x = 3) …` but not for `if ((x = 3)) …`.